# Laravel model eager loading is not working

Tags: laravel

I have a users table and posts table. A user can have many post, and a post only have a user. a typical 1:n relationship. what i wanna do is inserting post data trough user model (eager loading). like this one :

```
User::find(1)->posts()->insert(array(
            'title' => 'post 1',
            'body'  => 'lorem ipsum is just a dummy text'
        ));
```

this is User model :

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['username', 'email'];
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Post');
    }
}
```

this is my post model

```
class Post extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'user_id', 'body'];
    protected $table = 'posts';

}
```

and this is the post migration ( i made the user_id foreign to this table in order to supprt the relationship)

```
Schema::create('posts', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

The problem :
the data is inserted but the user_id = 0 and timestamps = 00000000

would anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `->save()`, not `->insert()`. Read this link: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#inserting-related-models

`->insert()` is using QueryBuilder which has no knowledge of your relationship, while `->save()` does (or `->saveMany()`)

```
User::find(1)->posts()->save(new Post(
            'title' => 'post 1',
            'body'  => 'lorem ipsum is just a dummy text'
        ));
```